# Building Scala 2.12 binaries from source code

Tags: scala, sbt

What is the complete sbt command to build scala 2.12.16 distributable binary for *Nix system (macOS & Linux)?

Scala 2.12.16 source zip : https://github.com/scala/scala/archive/refs/tags/v2.12.16.zip

*PS: `sbt publishLocal` builds scala compiler of latest stable version and then publishes to local ivy2 repo. So it is not helpful for me.*

Comment: `publishLocal` should give you the binary jar. The `scala` executable that gets installed in `/usr/bin` is just a bash script that searches for the jar in $SCALA_HOME and executes it

Comment: Why do you even want to do this?

Comment: Why not? Your question is invalid. So you think a person should never a build anything from sources and just use the binaries provided by the maintainer?

Comment: If you want to build release packages, the machinery for that lives in another repo, namely https://github.com/scala/scala-dist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Seth Tisue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86485/seth-tisue) for providing git repo information.

git repo for building scala distributable binary https://github.com/scala/scala-dist.git

sbt command `universal:packageBin`

Complete command to build scala 2.12.x binaries from sources:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/scala/scala-dist.git
cd scala-dist
git checkout 2.12.x
sbt clean universal:packageBin
```

after firing the above command binaries will be present in `target/universal/scala-2.12.16.zip`